# How to Change Coordinate Systems in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, coordinate-systems, space-expansion

Let me preface by stating that I have no experience with General Relativity. I am working on a project for school that requires a little knowledge of it, so I am hoping to find some help. I do have experience with Special Relativity.

On to the question. I know that one can calculate the age of the Universe using the Lambda-CDM model. After making a few simplifying assumptions, one can find the relation

$$H\left ( a \right )=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}=H_{0}\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_{m}}{a^{3}}+\frac{\Omega_{rad}}{a^{4}}+\Omega_{\Lambda }}.$$

One can numerically integrate to find $t_{0}$, the age of the Universe.

$$t_{0}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{da}{aH_{0}\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_{m}}{a^{3}}+\frac{\Omega_{rad}}{a^{4}}+\Omega_{\Lambda }}}$$

Now, if I am correct, when performing this calculation for the age, I was working in a co-variant coordinate system (the system that expands with the universe or the system of CMB). For my project, I want to calculate the age of the Universe in a different coordinate system. More specifically, I would like to calculate the age in a coordinate system that is not expanding with the Universe. I know from other articles on here that I cannot use Special Relativity, but I am unsure how to go about this. If someone could show me how to go about this, keeping in mind my knowledge on this subject is very limited, I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $ds^2$ as $a^2$ times a static metric, introducing a new time coordinate viz. $d\eta=dt/a$. We say the full metric is conformal to the simpler one (this adjective refers to angle preservation upon the rescaling), so $\eta$ is called conformal time. The $\eta r\theta\phi$ coordinate system fits your criterion.

Note that $d\eta=da/(a^2 H)$; the conformal age of the universe, in the convention where $a=1$ today, is about $46.8$ Gigayears, which is why the Hubble zone is $93.8$ light Gigayears wide. Thus the conformal age is not the quantity you want! You should still integrate $da/(aH)$ instead, but write $a,\,H$ as functions of $\eta$ instead of $t$.

Comment: So here is what I got: $$H\left ( a \right )=\frac{\dot{a}}{a\left ( t \right )}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{\mathrm{d} a}{\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{\mathrm{d} a}{\mathrm{d} \eta }\frac{\mathrm{d} \eta }{\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{{a\left ( \eta  \right )}'}{a\left ( \eta  \right )^{2}}$$$$a\left ( t \right )=a\left ( \eta  \right )$$ This does not quite seem correct. If it is not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: @JavaNewbie No, you are right; your result is equivalent to my own calculation.

Comment: Using the Friedmann equation $$\frac{\dot{a}^{2}+kc^{2}}{a^{2}}=\frac{8\pi G\rho +\Lambda c^{2}}{3}$$ and using $k=0$, I found $${a}'=\sqrt{\frac{8\pi G\rho+\Lambda c^{2}}{3}}a^{2}.$$ From the definitions from my last comment, $$t_{0}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{a}{{a}'}\mathrm{d} a=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{\frac{3}{8\pi G\rho+\Lambda c^{2}}}\mathrm{d}a.$$ Is this correct? Also, how do I then get $\rho$ in terms of $\Omega_{m}$, $\Omega_{rad}$, and $\Omega_{\Lambda }$. Finally, will the values of these parameters remain unchanged from the original ones?

Comment: On second glance, I found $$\eta _{0}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d} a}{H_{0}\sqrt{\Omega _{m}a+\Omega _{rad}+\Omega _{\Lambda }a^{4}}}\cong 46.3\:\mathrm{billion\:years.}$$ I kept all the parameters the same as before. I am a little confused as this is the quantity you said I didn't want.

Comment: @JavaNewbie You want the age of the. universe, which is the smaller value called $t_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am a little confused. Are my integrals wrong for calculating the quantity I am after? If so, what is the integral I will be evaluating?

Comment: You said, "I want to calculate the age of the Universe in a different coordinate system". The phrase "age of the Universe" refers to $t_0$; $\eta_0$ is a different quantity called the conformal time ($c\eta_0$ is a comoving distance). See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_horizon#Conformal_time_and_the_particle_horizon

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I understand I must find $t_{0}$, but are you saying that the $t_{0}$ in this new coordinate system will be the same in the co-variant coordinate system I mentioned in my initial question? More specifically, how can I calculate the age of the Universe in the new system of coordinates. From Special Relativity, I know that time depends on one's reference frame. I assume this is true for coordinate systems in General Relativity.

Comment: @JavaNewbie Not all coordinate system changes affect the total age. In fact, those that do are undesirable because they destroy isotropy of space. For example, SR's time dilation due to a Lorentz boost would choose a privileged direction in space.

Comment: That is very interesting. So are you saying that the new coordinate system I am after will yield the same age for the Universe? Or are you saying that the age in this coordinate system is undesirable? If it is the latter, I would still like to calculate it, even if it is not something typically sought.

Comment: @JavaNewbie Both $t_0$ and $\eta_0$ are sought at times, and you're already computed each; you just need to be careful how you describe them. "Age of the universe" means $t_0$; "conformal age of the universe" means $\eta_0$.

Comment: Ignoring the obvious impossibility, imagine an observer of the big bang who witnesses the subsequent expansion of the Universe. This observer does not expand with the Universe (thus, their coordinate system is not expanding). Which of these two times, if either, do they see for the age of the Universe? Or has a different amount of time elapsed for them? I have read a published article that, if I remember correctly, found this to be significantly smaller than the "Age of the Universe". I am unable to find the article, but I am trying to work out the math of a similar scenario.

Comment: @JavaNewbie They should experience a time $t_0$; the article might have been pointing out this is substantially less than the value $\eta_0$ that gives $c^{-1}$ times the Hubble zone's radius.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand (probably from a lack of understanding). To me it seems if this individual sent a pulse of light every second, we would not receive one every second on earth. Since the Universe has expanded, it would take much longer for each pulse of light to arrive. Thus, just throwing out numbers, say we receive one pulse every 10 seconds, the individual would experience 1 second for every 10 seconds we experience. That would cut the age they see down to about 1.38 billion years. I believe that is a similar argument to the one they made.

Comment: @JavaNewbie If you find it, please share a link.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the same way as before but assume $\Omega_{rad}$ is currently very small

$$\frac {\dot a}{a}=H_{0}\sqrt{\Omega_{m}a^{-3} + \Omega_{\Lambda}}$$

which has the solution

$$a(t)=(\Omega_{m}/\Omega_{\Lambda})^{1/3}\sinh^{2/3}(t/t_{\Lambda})$$

where $t_{\Lambda}=2/(3H_{0}\sqrt{\Omega_{\Lambda} })$

Set $a=1$ which gives you $t=t_{0}$ the current age of the Universe.

See the Lambda-CDM model in Wikipedia.